# why did my variable not received all the elements from my archive when I executed the command: value="`cat archive.txt`"?

Tags: bash

I want to extract information associated with id numbers that is content in an archive (named 'data.txt') using an other archive (named 'MIM_ids.txt') that contain exclusively a set of id numbers of my interest.

Illustration of what I trying to explain:

[image: illustration of what I trying to explain XD]

My process was the following: I generated the archive MIM_ids.txt from another archive called MIM_ids_chromosome.txt: `cut -f2 MIM_ids_chromosome.txt > MIM_ids.txt`, then I try to assign its content on the variable 'value': 'data.txt':`value="`cat MIM_ids.txt`"`, but only the last id number were assigned to my variable. The problem is the form I generated the archive 'MIM_ids.txt', to verify, I tried to generate it just copying and pasting a set of id numbers on an archive and  then assign it to the variable, surprisingly it work very well. Why does this strategy not function when I generate the archive in the first manner?

On another hand, when I have my variable with the example content and try to extract the information from the 'data.txt' archive by the command grep using the id numbers: `grep -F "${value}" data.txt > extracted.txt`, it function but not properly, I mean, information is missing, and I verify that all the ids was content in thar file matching rudimentarily one by one. Why does the grep command not match all the variable ids?

Comment: The complete code:
cut -f2 MIM_ids_chromosome.txt > MIM_ids.txt;




value="`cat MIM_ids.txt`";



grep -F "${value}" data.txt > extracted.txt

Comment: Please read a few highly rated `bash` Q/As and convert your Q to the form of 1. Small sample input, 2. required output from input, 3. current code, 4. current output, 5 error messages 6. thoughts about why its not working. Use the `{}` tool on the edit box toolbar on highlighted text to keep the format. Good luck.

Comment: You're not really using typesetting dbl-quotes as shown in the headline Q? Be sure to use `"cat ..."` (straight dbl-quotes). Good luck.

Comment: Do you want to find all occurrences of the second field from `MM_ids_chromosome.txt` in `data.txt`? Does the output order matter?

Comment: `grep -wF <(cut -f2 MIM_ids_chromosome.txt) data.txt` maybe?

Comment: Thanks  @MarkSetchell , but I executed it and does not work,it`s an excellent idea to cut the column within the grep command, but I do not know how to make it woks.

Comment: Now I'm betting that one or both of your files have been through an MS-Windows system. If so, use `dos2unix MIM_ids_chromosome.txt data.txt` and try all of these ideas again. Good luck.

Comment: thaks @shellter. What do you mean with MS-Windows system? Windows operating system?

Comment: Yeah, but the crucial detail is the other system's line ending convention. See the [Stack Overflow `bash` tag wiki](/tags/bash/info) for troubleshooting tips for this extremely common FAQ.

Comment: Yes the problem was It did not have DOS style end-of-line characters, and the command dos2unix is necessary to function the assign to the variable. Thanks @shellter, @tripleee!